# "Temporary failure in name resolution" after updating to 20.10

Tags: networking, dns

I just updated from 20.04 to 20.10 and am now getting no DNS with my wired network (no wireless on this computer):

```
alpaca:adrian> ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I looked in /etc/resolv.conf:

```
alpaca:adrian> cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search DOMAINS
```

resolv.conf is a link to ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

```
alpaca:adrian> systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no     
MulticastDNS setting: no     
  DNSOverTLS setting: no     
      DNSSEC setting: no     
    DNSSEC supported: no     
          DNS Domain: DOMAINS

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: none   
DefaultRoute setting: no     
       LLMNR setting: yes    
MulticastDNS setting: no     
  DNSOverTLS setting: no     
      DNSSEC setting: no     
    DNSSEC supported: no     
          DNS Domain: DOMAINS
alpaca:adrian> nmcli device show eth0  
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         70:71:BC:DD:29:17
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.99/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::7271:bcff:fedd:2917/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

I thought networking was controlled by /etc/network/interfaces, which lists DNS servers:

```
alpaca:adrian> cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
       address 192.168.1.99
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 192.168.1.1
       dns-nameservers 68.100.16.25 68.100.16.30  68.105.28.12
       dns-search cox.net
```

If I look at the network button at the top of the unity environment it says networking is "unmanaged" and doesn't list anything.  I tried adding a network but this didn't seem to have any effect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In a desktop installation, networking is properly controlled by Network Manager; in a server by netplan. The file */etc/network/interfaces* is deprecated. Therefore, I suggest that you revert the file to its default:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Next, your /etc/resolv.conf file is currently a link to the wrong place. Let's fix it:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf  /etc/resolv.conf
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes, this has gotten the networking to function work working nameserver.   I made a "manual" network entry and included the info from my /etc/network/interfaces file and that seems to have reproduced the previous behavior.  Is there a file one can edit that has those settings instead of using the GUI network config menu?

Comment: I suggest the GUI for the network settings. Please tell us the settings you entered.

Comment: I normally use the FVWM window manager.  How can I invoke the GUI network settings program?  The settings I entered are the ones that appear in my old /etc/network/interfaces file.  Going from memory here, I think I selected "manual" instead of DHCP, then I put in the IP, netmask and gateway as the first entry list a list of addresses, and finally I listed the DNS servers and domain.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am completly unfamiliar with FVWM. Please look around and find the Network Manager GUI and let us see a screenshot. It might look something like this: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zXKEt3vxNg4/T58h-Cm1HJI/AAAAAAAAAjs/uOC0tCLcS4w/s1600/ScreenHunter_02%2BApr.%2B30%2B16.37.gif

Comment: Everything works now, so what are you trying to fix?   The FVWM setup is very old school.  There is nowhere to "look" to find the GUI.  I need to know the program name to run if I want to see a GUI (or if I want to add it to the FVWM menus).

Comment: You can use the text one: nmtui  ... and for audio, pavucontrol ;-)